# Sufficient condition on rank of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, determinant

Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Show that the determinant map $\det: M_n(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is infinitely diffeentiable and compute the total derivative $d(\det)$ at every point of $A\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$. Find a necessary and sufficient condition on the rank of $A$ for $d(\det)=0$ on $A$..

I really do not know how to find derivative of determinant map..

Let $n=2$ for simplicity...

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
then $df:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \{\rm{maps~} \mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\}$ with $df(a)=\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a)~\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(a)\right)$ and $df(x)(x_1,x_2)=x_1\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a)+x_2\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(a)$

Consider $\det:M_2(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $\begin{bmatrix}x&y\\z&w\end{bmatrix}\mapsto xw-yz$ then,

$$d(\det)\begin{bmatrix}a_1&a_2\\a_3&a_4\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}a_3&-a_4\\-a_2&a_1\end{bmatrix}$$

Now i am confused... Do we have

$$d(\det)\begin{bmatrix}a_1&a_2\\a_3&a_4\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}b_1&b_2\\b_3&b_4\end{bmatrix}= 
\begin{bmatrix}a_3&-a_4\\-a_2&a_1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}b_1&b_2\\b_3&b_4\end{bmatrix}=a_3b_1-a_4b_2-a_2b_3+a_1b_4$$

I do not know where to go from here...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula

Comment: @user251257 : Thanks but that was not so exciting..

Comment: Well, you showed that at least for $n=2$ the matrix has to be the zero matrix. You could do a similar thing in the case $n=3$.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp : I do not understand... Matrix has to be zero matrix??

Comment: Yes. Your last formula is nonsense. But the one before is correct (I would write the derivative as a vector, though). So, the derivative of the determinant at A is zero if and only if the matrix on the right hand side is zero. But this is the case if and only if A is zero. If you do the similar thing in the case n=3, you will see that all 2x2 subdeterminants must be zero which is equivalent to the matrix having rank 1. So, it seems that the condition is rank A = n-2. This could be proved by induction using Laplace. EDIT: Why don't you incoorporate "necessary" in the title?

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp : I do not know what is nonsense? PLease copy paste here so that there is no ambiguity...

Comment: What is ambigous in "your last formula"? It's the last formula you wrote in your very first post. It's wrong resp. nonsense. EDIT: Now, I understood what you did. However, the derivative of det in A is supposed to be zero. So, all its components have to be zero. You don't need to apply it to another matrix.

Comment: Is it still nonsense... ? @FriedrichPhilipp

Comment: It is ok, although the last equality is the scalar product of the matrices and not - as it suggests - a matrix multiplication. Please see the edit in my last comment.

Comment: So, you are saying that it is now correct except that i was denoting it as a matrix multiplication... @FriedrichPhilipp... how can i extend this to general $n\times n$ matrix

Comment: First task: Read my comments!

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp : Yes.. I will.. Some how i missed it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example (3x3): You have
$$
\det (A) = \left|\begin{matrix} a & b & c\\d & e & f\\g & h & i\end{matrix}\right| = a\left|\begin{matrix}e & f\\h & i\end{matrix}\right| - b\left|\begin{matrix}d & f\\g & i\end{matrix}\right| + c\left|\begin{matrix}d & e\\g & h\end{matrix}\right|.
$$
That is,
$$
\frac{\partial\det}{\partial a}(A) = \left|\begin{matrix}e & f\\h & i\end{matrix}\right|,\quad \frac{\partial\det}{\partial b}(A) = -\left|\begin{matrix}d & f\\g & i\end{matrix}\right|,\quad \frac{\partial\det}{\partial c}(A) = \left|\begin{matrix}d & e\\g & h\end{matrix}\right|.
$$
Hence, all these determinants have to be zero. Now, do the same stuff for d, e, and f, where you apply Laplace to the second row of the matrix. Thereafter, do it again for g, h, and i. You will see that the condition $D(det)(A) = 0$ means that all 2x2 subdeterminants have to vanish. This again is equivalent to the matrix A having rank at most 1 (why?). Try to generalize this approach to the case of nxn matrices.

Comment: As all $2\times 2$ deteminants are zero... determinant of $A$ zero.. So, det $A$ is zero.. As all $2\times 2$ deteminants are zero...  rank can not be $2$.. So, rank can be at most $1$... Similarly in case of $n\times n$ matrix, all $n-1\times n-1$ determinants are zero so rank can be atmost $n-2$...

Comment: That's how it works. Of course you will have to explain why all kxk subdeterminants being zero is equivalent to the matrix having rank at most k-1.

Comment: I think i have said that... rank of a matrix is maximal order of submatrix with non zero determinant... So, all $n-1$ determinants are zero... So, rank can be atmost $n-2$,,,  I am sure you mean $n-2$ and not $k-1$

Comment: Usually, the rank of a matrix is defined via the maximal number of linear independent rows/columns. If you have the subdeterminant definition - alright. And by k I meant k, not necessarily n-1.